# Смена элемента в навигации при прокрутке страницы

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, эффекты

Добрый день, уважаемые знатоки!)
Если зайти [сюда](https://www.thestar.com/news/canada/2016/05/14/fundraiser-held-for-bc-mother-of-abducted-azer-kids-who-wants-trudeaus-help.html) и прокрутить страницу по всей высоте, можно заметить, что элементы навигационного меню сменяются элементами со страницы. Кто-то может пояснить, как такое сделать?

P.S. если я все правильно понял, там используется React.js. Можно обойтись без него?

Comment: попробуй это http://getuikit.com/docs/sticky.html

Comment: @sashatexb спасибо, будем пробовать)

Answer (score 1):

Это, видимо, попытка обыграть новое css свойство position:sticky

```
position:sticky;
position:-webkit-sticky;
```

Но [здесь](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sticky-positioning-with-nothing-but-css--cms-24042) пишут, что Хром этот тип position теперь не поддерживает. Видимо Javascript'ом они добавляют position:fixed кнопкам меню и блоку .position-sticky при определенном скролле